# How can I select a property from an object type column in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is table :

```
Id    source_data           name

1.    {id: '1', value: 5}.  Ahmed
2.    {id: '3', value: 7}.  Aadi
```

I want to do this kind of query:
Select Id, source_data.value, name
From table

Comment: What data type is `source_data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the data type of your `source_data` column is type `json` or `jsonb`:

```
SELECT
    id,
    source_data ->> 'value'
    name
FROM my_table
```

If it is of type `text`, you can cast it into `json` before:

```
SELECT
    id,
    source_data::json ->> 'value'
    name
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @s-man. I really appreciate your help.